# Need approach to run Spring batch continuously

Tags: spring, spring-batch

We are using Spring batch which will fetch x number of records from Database and Make API call and again update database for those x records and this process we are running in 2 steps but we dont want it to be running as scheduler want this to be executed as continuous process as if step 2 is done we should re-execute job , Can someone Please help us as is this recommended approach to run batch continuously for set fo specific batch size of x records and its impact on performance?

Comment: why not a simple `while (true)`?..

Comment: any impact in terms of perf if we fetch 10K record in each iteration form DB and after successful processing of those again make call to DB to fetch next set of 10K , is this right use case for spring batch as its designed for large batch processing.